# Swift FB Login always returning "isCancelled"

Tags: swift, appdelegate, fbsdk

I've successfully logged into Facebook through my app probably 50 to 100 times but now it's not working.  I got the login screen and can put in my FB login information or hit continue due to already having logged in.  When the login screen is dismissed, the callbacks are being called but result.isCancelled is always true.  Here's the delegate function I'm using:

```
func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result:
    FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {

    print(result.isCancelled)       //always returning true
}
```

Here's what I have in appDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

    return true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {

    let handled = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)

    return handled
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

    FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
}
```

Is there any way to check the activation status of the app?  I'm wondering if the issue is in the general setup somehow (e.g., p-list, Facebook developers site, etc.).

UPDATE:  I'm also now getting crashes on FB shares, which I've also checked previously.  Here's the error message.  It seems like these have to be related.

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
    frame #0: 0x0000000101b2faa4 libswiftCore.dylib`swift_getObjectType + 60
    frame #1: 0x00000001005d6acc Word Duel`@objc AppDelegate.application(_:open:sourceApplication:annotation:) at AppDelegate.swift:0
    frame #2: 0x000000018e678acc UIKit`__58-[UIApplication _applicationOpenURLAction:payload:origin:]_block_invoke + 880
    frame #3: 0x000000018e678440 UIKit`-[UIApplication _applicationOpenURLAction:payload:origin:] + 596
    frame #4: 0x0000000199a75990 SafariServices`-[SFSafariViewController remoteViewController:hostApplicationOpenURL:] + 216
    frame #5: 0x0000000199a67834 SafariServices`-[SFBrowserRemoteViewController willOpenURLInHostApplication:] + 76
    frame #6: 0x00000001846ca580 CoreFoundation`__invoking___ + 144
    frame #7: 0x00000001845a9748 CoreFoundation`-[NSInvocation invoke] + 284
    frame #8: 0x0000000102379220 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 16
    frame #9: 0x0000000102385850 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 232
    frame #10: 0x0000000186ef4878 FrontBoardServices`__FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 36
    frame #11: 0x0000000186ef451c FrontBoardServices`-[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 404
    frame #12: 0x0000000186ef4ab8 FrontBoardServices`-[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56
    frame #13: 0x000000018466b404 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
    frame #14: 0x000000018466ac2c CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 276
    frame #15: 0x000000018466879c CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1204
    frame #16: 0x0000000184588da8 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
    frame #17: 0x000000018656b020 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 100
    frame #18: 0x000000018e56978c UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 236
  * frame #19: 0x00000001005d89c0 Word Duel`main at AppDelegate.swift:18
    frame #20: 0x0000000184019fc0 libdyld.dylib`start + 4
```

Comment: Okay, so the login issue just spontaneously resolved itself.  I did add `fbauth2` for `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` in the p-list, but I tried several times before it worked so it must be spontaneous or something on FB's end.  Still getting the share crash.

Comment: @WizKid Help this guy